# Sidekiq job priority

Tags: sidekiq

The task which was enqued using perform_async was in progress and was taking the time approximately 5 min and at 3rd minute I run job using perform_in after 10 seconds so what will be first executing? The task which was already enqued using perform_aync or the task which was enqued using perform_in ?

I have tried it but not find the correct solution.